# How to initiate a new columns with None and update its value with tuple conditionally?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following code

```
import pandas as pd
d = [{'points': 50, 'time': '5:00', 'year': 2010},
     {'points': 25, 'time': '6:00', 'month': "february"},
     {'points': 90, 'time': '9:00', 'month': 'january'},
     {'points_h1': 20, 'month': 'june'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df['auditor'] = None
df.loc[df['points'] == 50, 'auditor'] = (1, 2)
print(df)
print(df.loc[df['points'] == 50, 'auditor'])
```

I want to initiate a new column and with `None` and conditionally update its value with a `tuple` but it occurs the following error.

```
ValueError: cannot set using a multi-index selection indexer with a different length than the value
```

my desire result is

```
      month  points  points_h1  time  year  auditor
0       NaN      50        NaN  5:00  2010  (1,2)
1  february      25        NaN  6:00   NaN  None
2   january      90        NaN  9:00   NaN  None
3      june     NaN         20   NaN   NaN  None
```

how may I do so?

Comment: What do you mean by conditionally update its value? What is your desired end result?

Comment: @jdaz conditionally i mean i could update the auditor row value based on certain condition is met e.g. `df['point'] == 50` leave while others unchanged `df.loc[df['points'] == 50, 'auditor'] = (1, 2)` , i included the desired result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use `np.where()` which is a good function for conditions:

```
df['auditor'] = np.where((df['points'] == 50), pd.Series([(1, 2)]), None)
```

OR in one line when creating the dataframe with `.assign()`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d).assign(auditor=np.where((df['points'] == 50), pd.Series([(1, 2)]), None))
```

---

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
d = [{'points': 50, 'time': '5:00', 'year': 2010},
     {'points': 25, 'time': '6:00', 'month': "february"},
     {'points': 90, 'time': '9:00', 'month': 'january'},
     {'points_h1': 20, 'month': 'june'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(d).assign(auditor=np.where((df['points'] == 50), pd.Series([(1, 2)]), None))
df

Out[34]: 
   points  time    year     month  points_h1 auditor
0    50.0  5:00  2010.0       NaN        NaN  (1, 2)
1    25.0  6:00     NaN  february        NaN    None
2    90.0  9:00     NaN   january        NaN    None
3     NaN   NaN     NaN      june       20.0    None
```

---

Per your comment, if you want to manually create conditions and results and then loop through the `np.where()`, then this is how you would do it:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
d = [{'points': 50, 'time': '5:00', 'year': 2010},
     {'points': 25, 'time': '6:00', 'month': "february"},
     {'points': 90, 'time': '9:00', 'month': 'january'},
     {'points_h1': 20, 'month': 'june'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

#Manually Set Conditions and Rsults
c1 = (df['points'] == 50)
r1 =  pd.Series([(1, 2)])
c2 = (df['points'] == 25)
r2 = pd.Series([(1, 3)])
conditions = [c1,c2]
results = [r1,r2]

df['auditor'] = None
for c, r in zip(conditions, results):
    df['auditor'] = np.where(c, r, df['auditor'])
df

Out[39]: 
   points  time    year     month  points_h1 auditor
0    50.0  5:00  2010.0       NaN        NaN  (1, 2)
1    25.0  6:00     NaN  february        NaN  (1, 3)
2    90.0  9:00     NaN   january        NaN    None
```

---

See Anky's comments. Instead of:

```
df['auditor'] = None
    for c, r in zip(conditions, results):
        df['auditor'] = np.where(c, r, df['auditor'])
```

you can use `np.select` to avoid looping. This is a more pythonic. efficient way to do this:

```
df['auditor'] = np.select(conditions,results,None)
```

Comment: It is a neat answer. although it does answer this question, but when i put the `df['auditor'] = np.where((df['points'] == 50), pd.Series([(1, 2)]), None)` into a for loop even the condition is different the auditor column will be replaced.. any chance to improve it?

Comment: Instead of loop for multiple conditions , you can also use `np.select` : `np.select(conditions,results,None)` :-)

Answer (score 2):

Since you cant be sure that the condition would return just 1 row or multiple rows, it is better to create a series of tuples and repeat it according to the number of rows returned by the condition:

```
condition = df['points'] == 50
df.loc[condition, 'auditor'] = pd.Series([(1, 2)]).repeat(condition.sum()).values
```

---

```
print(df)

   points  time    year     month  points_h1 auditor
0    50.0  5:00  2010.0       NaN        NaN  (1, 2)
1    25.0  6:00     NaN  february        NaN    None
2    90.0  9:00     NaN   january        NaN    None
3     NaN   NaN     NaN      june       20.0    None
```

---

To see what I mean , let's consider the second row also had `points` as 50:

```
d = [{'points': 50, 'time': '5:00', 'year': 2010},
 {'points': 50, 'time': '6:00', 'month': "february"},
 {'points': 90, 'time': '9:00', 'month': 'january'},
 {'points_h1': 20, 'month': 'june'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df['auditor'] = None
print(df,'\n\n')

condition = df['points'] == 50
df.loc[condition, 'auditor'] = pd.Series([(1, 2)]).repeat(condition.sum()).values
print(df)
```

---

```
   points  time    year     month  points_h1 auditor
0    50.0  5:00  2010.0       NaN        NaN    None
1    50.0  6:00     NaN  february        NaN    None
2    90.0  9:00     NaN   january        NaN    None
3     NaN   NaN     NaN      june       20.0    None 


   points  time    year     month  points_h1 auditor
0    50.0  5:00  2010.0       NaN        NaN  (1, 2)
1    50.0  6:00     NaN  february        NaN  (1, 2)
2    90.0  9:00     NaN   january        NaN    None
3     NaN   NaN     NaN      june       20.0    None
```

Comment: Thank you for keeping it in the panda context, would you mind explaining why this error happens and `.repeat(condition.sum()).values`? it looks very unusual to me..

Comment: @chris_2020 when you assign `(1, 2)` as a value, pandas unpacks it to 2 row values , 1 and 2 , hence it says `different length than the value`